# How to change shared sub repository url

Tags: mercurial, clone, mercurial-subrepos

we have a replica of repository that is updated every 4 hours pointing to another url. Problem is .hgsub has path that is still pointing to original repository URL. How can we change the sub repository path in replica repository. As we are getting clone failed error every time it tries to update sub repository. Please guide

Answer (score 1):

Use the `[subpaths]` section of the replica's `.hg/hgrc` file.  Something like this:

```
[subpaths]
http://path/to/original = /path/to/local/replica
```

That will tell it whenever going to the original path instead go to the local replacement.

Details here: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#subpaths